# Trigger dbt job via API using PR number (PR id)

Tags: continuous-integration, dbt

I'm trying to trigger jobs via API (for CI), from my GitHub CI pipeline when PRs are approved.

According to [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cloud/api-v2#/operations/Trigger%20Job%20Run) see we have tree options for triggering the jobs: `git_sha`, `git_branch` or `github_pull_request_id`.

- The git_branch in my case is not straightforward to get since after approval the github changes the ref (and doesn't return the branch name anymore)
- the sha is an option
- and I'm currently trying to use the github_pull_request_id.
- Although when trying the request below, I'm having the following error.
  Request example

```
curl --location 'https://cloud.getdbt.com/api/v2/accounts/acc_id/jobs/jb_id/run/' \
--header 'Authorization: Token token' \
--form 'cause="Triggered by GH Actions"' \
--form 'github_pull_request_id="3209"' \
--form 'schema_override="DBT_CLOUD_PR_81231_3209"'
```

Error:

```
"github_pull_request_id": "'3209' is not valid under any of the given schemas"
```

What's the expected ID number for `github_pull_request_id` (I'm sending the PR number)?

Comment: IDK why dbt has this erro. I used git_sha instead. Using this flag for checkout on last commit instead of merge commit: https://github.com/actions/checkout#Checkout-pull-request-HEAD-commit-instead-of-merge-commit

Comment: out of curiosity: why aren't you using Slim CI instead of this to automatically trigger a dbt job on each dev branch when a PR is open?

Comment: because every change on PR will trigger a new run in dbt and in SF, what you increase SF costs